# Changing the Header value in Grid View

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

Using VS2005

I am using Gridview in my web page, when i load the web page, the table header also displaying in the GridView. So i want to give my different header name in datagridview.

So how to change the setting in datagridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `HeaderText="FirstName"` property of you column as below

```
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName"
                                            ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to add

```
<HeaderTemplate> Name </HeaderTemplate>
```